# Tkinter: how to make window appear when a button is pressed

Tags: python, window, tkinter

I want to create a window with Tkinter. This window should have a button.
When the button is pressed, I want a second window to appear (without the disappearance of the first).

The code, shortened:

```
from Tkinter import *
from modules.startingKit.highscore import Highscore


class OptionWindow:

    def __init__(self):
        self.master = Tk() 
        self.b4 = Button(self.master, text = "display Highscores", command = self.display()).grid(row=0, sticky = W)
    mainloop()



    def display(self):
        myWin = Toplevel()
```

Well, the second window IS displayed, but before I press the button. Can I change this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `command` attribute takes a *reference* to a function. When you do `command=self.display()`, you are *calling* the function and passing the result to the `command` attribute.

The fix is to omit the parenthesis:

```
self.b4 = Button(..., command=self.display, ...)
```